# The Boot Camp USB drivers paradox

Tags: bootcamp, usb, windows, driver

I have following problem: I have Boot Camp Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.2). I observed, that I couldn't connect USB flash drives to that Windows system, so I installed all Boot Camp drivers from the Boot Camp Assistant. I copied them to a USB flash drive and installed them on the Windows 7 partition. The problem was, that when I connected a USB flash drive to my Windows 7 partition, it was recognized as Generic USB. I actually couldn't eject it anymore. I read somewhere that this error was caused due to a version of the Intel USB driver i had installed earlier. That's why I deleted the Intel USB driver in the control panel. Now I can't seem to connect USB flash drives at all. I tried to drag the drivers to the Windows 7 partition via VMware, but it didn't work. When I double-click on **setup.exe**, it won't start.

I have access to following programs or systems: VMware Fusion, Boot Camp Assistant, Windows 7, OS X partition.

How can I install the Intel USB drivers since I can't use an USB on my MacBook?

Comment: email it to yourself, or push it to Dropbox etc

Comment: Beaten me to it! :-P

Comment: I'm trying to push the files to Dropbox and then install them from there on the win7 partition. Puuh 1.32 GB upload, I think I will go drink a coffee. I will let you guys know later how it went. Thanks for the replies anyway ;)

Comment: What a waste of bandwidth!  I'd temporarily mount the Windows volume Read/Write, copy the files over and then unmount it.

Comment: It worked, I could install it from the Dropbox folder.  @user3439894 I used the internet from my school on a Saturday, so I guess it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could upload the drivers to a service such as Dropbox...